# Blue color table border using docx4j

Tags: colors, border, docx4j

I'm using docx4j to create a docx file. I want my table border to be blue colored but it is only showing black.how to do this?

Here is my code:

```
            table.setTblPr(new TblPr()); 
            CTBorder border = new CTBorder();   
            border.setColor("FFF");      
            border.setSz(new BigInteger("0")); 
            border.setSpace(new BigInteger("0"));
            border.setVal(STBorder.SINGLE);  
            TblBorders borders = new TblBorders();    
            borders.setBottom(border);     
            borders.setLeft(border);   
            borders.setRight(border);   
            borders.setTop(border);    
            borders.setInsideH(border); 
            borders.setInsideV(border);

            table.getTblPr().setTblBorders(borders);
```

Comment: Please add some code demonstrating the problem (http://sscce.org)

Comment: Specifically, the code you are using to create the table.  Can an answer assume you have a reference to the tbl object?

Comment: yes, jason tbl object is created.I juss need the code for coloring(blue) the border of the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the `color` attribute of the border in question. Your example code appears to have you setting a colour of 'FFF' which obviously won't work if it needs to be blue! I would suggest trying a straight blue in hex and going from there. For example a (very) standard blue would be:

```
CTBorder border = new CTBorder();
border.setColor("0000FF");
```

Comment: works perfectly with docx4j 8.2.3 & Java 1.8